# Best design pattern/approach for a long list of if/else/execute branches of code

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a "legacy" code that I want to refactor.
The code basically does a remote call to a server and gets back a reply. Then according to the reply executes accordingly.
Example of skeleton of the code:

```
public Object processResponse(String responseType, Object response) {
    if(responseType.equals(CLIENT_REGISTERED)) {  
       //code  
       //code ...
    }  
    else if (responseType.equals(CLIENT_ABORTED)) {
       //code  
       //code....
    }    
    else if (responseType.equals(DATA_SPLIT)) {
      //code
      //code... 
   }  
   etc
```

The problem is that there are many-many if/else branches and the code inside each if is not trivial.
So it becomes hard to maintain.
I was wondering what is that best pattern for this?
One thought I had was to create a single object with method names the same as the responseType and then inside processResponse just using reflection call the method with the same name as the responseType.
This would clean up processResponse but it moves the code to a single object with many/many methods and I think reflection would cause performance issues.
Is there a nice design approach/pattern to clean this up?

Answer (score 5):

Two approaches:

1. Strategy pattern http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/strategy-design-pattern
2. Create dictionary, where key is metadata (in your case metadata is responseType) and value is a function.

For example:

Put this in constructor

`responses = new HashMap<string, SomeAbstraction>();
responses.Put(CLIENT_REGISTERED, new ImplementationForRegisteredClient());
responses.Put(CLIENT_ABORTED, new ImplementationForAbortedClient());`

where `ImplementationForRegisteredClient` and `ImplementationForAbortedClient` implement `SomeAbstraction`

and call this dictionary via
`responses.get(responseType).MethodOfYourAbstraction(SomeParams);`

If you want to follow the principle of DI, you can inject this Dictionary in your client class.

Comment: In the strategy pattern though how do I use the proper strategy at runtime? E.g. in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java it just hardcodes an instance of a strategy while up each server reply how would I efficiently use the proper stategy?

Comment: TBH the dictionary example although good, IMO is not code we usually write in Java

Comment: @Jim Excuse me, I saw in the tags and Java automatically thought to javascript. I update my answer

Comment: +1. Good answer. The dictionary is nothing but a pre-instantiated factory. An alternate approach would be to create a class that instantiates the required implementation as and when required rather than creating them all together.

Answer (score 2):

My first cut would be to replace the if/else if structures with switch/case:

```
public Object processResponse(String responseType, Object response) {
    switch(responseType) {
        case CLIENT_REGISTERED: {  
       //code ...
    }  
    case CLIENT_ABORTED: {
       //code....
    }    
    case DATA_SPLIT: {
      //code... 
   }
```

From there I'd probably extract each block as a method, and from there apply the Strategy pattern.  Stop at whatever point feels right.

Comment: In the strategy pattern though how do I use the proper strategy at runtime? E.g. in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java it just hardcodes an instance of a strategy while up each server reply how would I efficiently use the proper stategy?

Answer (score 1):

The case you've describe seems to fit perfectly to the application of **Strategy pattern**. In particular, you've many variants of an algorithm, i.e. the code executed accordingly to the response of the remote server call.

Implementing the Stategy pattern means that you have to define a class hierachy, such the following:

```
public interface ResponseProcessor {
   public void execute(Context ctx);
}
class ClientRegistered implements ResponseProcessor {
   public void execute(Context ctx) {
      // Actions corresponding to a client that is registered
      // ...
   }
}
class ClientAborted implements ResponseProcessor {
   public void execute(Context ctx) {
      // Actions corresponding to a client aborted
      // ...
   }
}
// and so on...
```

The `Context` type should contain all the information that are needed to execute each 'strategy'. Note that if different strategies share some algorithm pieces, you could also use **Templeate Method pattern** among them.

You need a *factory* to create a particular Strategy at runtime. The factory will build a strategy starting from the response received. A possibile implementation should be the one suggested by @Sattar Imamov. The factory will contain the `if .. else` code.

If strategy classes are not to heavy to build and they don't need any external information at build time, you can also map each strategy to an Enumeration's value.

```
public enum ResponseType {
   CLIENT_REGISTERED(new ClientRegistered()),
   CLIENT_ABORTED(new ClientAborted()),
   DATA_SPLIT(new DataSplit());

   // Processor associated to a response
   private ResponseProcessor processor;

   private ResponseType(ResponseProcessor processor) {
      this.processor = processor;
   }
   public ResponseProcessor getProcessor() {
      return this.processor;
   }
}
```