# Inheritance vs hooks in abstract classes design approach

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class

I am refactoring a piece of code that has huge list of if/else branches.
I am using strategy pattern as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916857/best-design-pattern-approach-for-a-long-list-of-if-else-execute-branches-of-code) and have created a bunch of classes that implement the functionality inside the if branches.
Working on this I found that there are a few cases that the code does some "extra" work before actually doing the real work so now I want to make the sanest design decision:
1) Have something as follows:

```
public abstract class Processor {
    private abstract void mainProcess(Object o);
    protected void preProcess(Object o) {}
    public void process(Object o) {
       preProcess(o);  
       mainProcess(o);
    }
}
```

And very few classes will actually override and `preProcess` with specific logic while for the rest is just an "empty" hook.

2) Have something like:

```
public interface Processor {
   public void process(Object o);
}

    public class XProcessor implements Processor {
       @Override
       public void process(Object o) {
          //code here
       }
    }

    public class SpecialCaseProcessor extends XProcessor {
       private void preProcess(Object o) {
        //code here
       }

       @Override
       public void process(Object o) {
          preProcess(o);
          super.process(o);
       }
    }
```

To be honest I kind of like (1) but I don't like that only e.g. 5 out of 30 classes will actually implement the preprocess.

In (2) I avoid the empty hooks **but** I would need a way in my "constructor/factory" to distinguish between the specific extended subclasses

What is the sanest/most readable approach?

Comment: @GriffeyDog:You are right. I corrected OP to show my idea

Comment: Why have `preProcess` and `mainProcess` at all in this scenario if all you ever do with them is calling them directly after the other from `process`?

Comment: @PhilippWendler:In my mind it is like "enforcing" a recipe. In some cases I need a preprocess before the actual main processing and in others not

Comment: Why close? At least leave a comment on why

Comment: If you are ok if the recipe is not "enforced", you could simply implement the recipe in those processors that need it (as a private implementation detail), like in case 2) but without inheritance chain.

Comment: I look at this problem and the decorator pattern looks back at me: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have something like this -

1) `Processor` interface

2) `AbstractProcessor` abstract class which implements `Processor` and has `preProcess` abstract method.

3) Let your non-special case processors implement `Processor` and special case processors extend `AbstractProcessor` class.

I think this way you can avoid empty hooks and still distinguish between specific classes.